# Using Gravity Forms gform_after_submission to push submitted data to mySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, forms, gravity

I'm trying to use the gform_after_submission hook to push data to an externally hosted mySQL table. The script I am using is not showing any errors but also is not having any effect.

I am using the Wordpress plugin "Allow PHP in pages and posts" to put the hook straight into the page above the form short code (I am doing a similar thing - successfully - elsewhere on my site with a pre-populate hook, so I assume it is OK to use the same approach here).

Here's my code:

```
[allowphp]
add_action("gform_after_submission_9", "push_fields", 10, 2);
function push_fields($entry, $form){

$uploaderName = $entry["1"];
$organiserName = $entry["2"];
$organiserEmail = $entry["3"];
$organiserNumber = $entry["4"];
$venueNumber = $entry["5"];

$con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password*","dbname");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table (uploaderName, organiserName, 
organiserEmail, organiserNumber, venueNumber) VALUES ('$uploaderName',
'$organiserName', '$organiserEmail', '$organiserNumber', '$venueNumber')");
}
[/allowphp]
[gravityform id="9" name="Add your event"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be having an issue with the where you are calling the hook.  Right now you are calling the hook when the "the_content" hook is being called, and I'm not sure that is going to work.  To test out, I'd put a print_r( $entry ); die();  lines in the hook and see if you are actually getting the hook to fire.  If that doesn't work, you should move the code into the theme's functions.php file.  It should actually be there anyway, but that isn't the question you were asking.

If the placement of the hook isn't the issue, it most likely is the mysql query code block.  Since you are using word press, I'd leverage the global $wpdb object to insert the row into the db.  It would look something like this...

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(<sql statement>);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The short answer is that nothing you suggested has worked :-) "print_r( $entry ); die();" completely stopped any content from loading on the page. Inserting the code into functions.php crashed my entire website with the following error - "Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in .../wp-includes/functions.php on line 3865". Finally, I tried the $wpdb idea, it gave no errors but also had no effect (like my original code). Just FYI, I'm using my original mySQL query code elsewhere on my site and it's working fine.

Comment: Did you see the $entry array values when you printed them out? The error message you saw was b/c the callback function wasn't defined.  Did you also move the callback function to the function file? Follow this when you putting it in your functions file.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I was not seeing any $entry array values - just a totally blank page. Regarding functions.php: I inserted all the code between the [allowphp] tags of my original code, minus the "add_action" line. That stopped the site from crashing and giving that error code. I then put the "add_action" line into the page above the form short-code but it's back to square one I'm afraid - no errors but no effect either.

Comment: Just found out what the problem was - I didn't know there was more than one functions.php file. I've now added the code to wp-content/themes/selectedtheme/functions.php and it's working. Thanks for your time, Will.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. How about marking it as an accepted answer and help my reputation a little?